# Need to convert Left join SQL to linq query - help appreciated

Tags: c#, linq, left-join

Here is my code the issue I have is the less than comparison in the On clause ... Since Linq doesn't allow this .... Migrating down into the where clause wont work as I am comparing one of the fields to null.

Here is the sql query (THE a.UserID= is hardcoded for now)

```
SELECT A.Policy, A.Comments, A.EventDTTM, A.Status, A.Reason, A.FollowUp
                FROM PP_PolicyActivity A
                LEFT JOIN PP_PolicyActivity B
                ON(A.Policy = B.Policy AND A.EventDTTM < B.EventDTTM)
                WHERE A.UserID = 'Ixxxxxx' 
                AND B.EventDTTM IS NULL AND a.status = 'open - Pending'
                order by A.EventDTTM DESC
```

I need the result set from the above query as an IEnumerable list to populate a view

I'm tasked with rebuilding an old VB ASP NET that has a set of standing production databases behind it ... i don't have the option of changing the db design. I connecting to the server and database  and this query was going against a table on that database..  the model also reflects the layout of the actual table.

The problem is with A.EventDTTM < B.EventDTTM - I can't move this to the where clause as I also have to deal with B.EventDTTM IS NULL in the where clause.
I need to retool the query someway so that it is 'linq' friendly

```
 public class PolicyActivityModel
    {
        public string Policy { get; set; }
        public int PolicyID { get; set; }

        public string Status { get; set; }

        public string Reason { get; set; }

        public string Comments { get; set; }

        public DateTime EventDTTM { get; set; }

        public string UserID { get; set; }

        public DateTime FollowUp { get; set; }
    }
```

Company policy prohibits me from showing the connection string.

I am extremely new to Linq, Any help greatly appreciated

thank you

Comment: Usually, you have navigation properties in your object model and you don't need to write explicit joins. Can you show your object model or explain how you are connecting to your database through LINQ?

Comment: LINQ allows less than in the `Where` clause. `B.Where(b => A.EventDTTM < b.DTTM)`.

Comment: You said you can't change the database design; can you add the query as a stored procedure, and call that from your code?

Comment: No I can't add a stored procedure - black box scenario - I'm stuck with what I have.

Comment: I can't just drop that down into the where clause as It's also got check for B.EVENTDTTM as null

Comment: I assume this is EF? Which version? 6.x or 7? Are there valid foreign keys for navigation properties?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the navigation property after you get the policy from the database.

```
var policy = DbContext.First(x => x.Id == 1000);
var otherPolicies = policy.ConnectedPolicies.Where(p => ...);
```

Comment: A few possible problems with this: He didn't call out EF, He might not have valid foreign keys (thus no navigation properties) and he's self-joining the tables...

Comment: Actually, he didn’t but I bet it will be useful for those who use it even if he doesn’t. The user who asked the question is using a database so I may have extrapolated. Anyway, your answer may help him too. Thanks

Comment: Agreed! And I left him a comment on it, if he has it this is the short easy answer. If not... The Original database designer needs a lesson in designing a decent schema...

Answer (score 0):

It's weird being a self-join but this is the most direct translation to Linq:

```
var query = from leftPP in PP_PolicyActivity 
     join rightPP in PP_PolicyActivity
          on new { Policy = leftPP.Policy, EventDTTM = leftPP.EventDTTM } 
          equals new { Policy = rightPP.Policy, EventDTTM = rightPP.EventDTTM }
          into pp from joinedRecords.DefaultIfEmpty()
where leftPP.UserId == 1 
      && leftPP.EventDTTM < rightPP.DTTM)
      && rightPP.EventDTTM == null 
      && leftPP.status = "open - Pending"
select new
{
    leftPP,
    rightPP
}
```

I free typed this, without models or Intellisense, thus there might be some smaller errors.

You could add the order by in that clause, but it's also still an IQUeryable, so I'd leave it.

And then, to get a List of models:

```
var results = query.OrderByDescending(x => x.EventDTTM).ToList();
```

The actual join is lines 2,3,4 and 5. It's verbose and "backwards" from SQL, and most importantly uses anonymous types. Accessing indidual properties will look something like:

```
 results[0].leftPP.PolicyId
```